# iOS Snapchat Style - UIPanGestureRecognizer Within UITableViewCell And UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I'd like to give a go at implementing the same functionality of Snapchat specific to the way you get into a text chat with a friend in that app.

I have three view controllers in a `UIPageViewController`. The middle view controller is a `UITableViewController` with an expandable cell and five subcells that appear when the cell is expanded. I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in each of the subcells where as you slide to the left on a cell, a button is revealed. However, both the pan gesture recognizer and the `UIPageController` sliding to another view controller are happening at the same time. How do I disable the `UIPageViewController` sliding until a user is sliding the `UITableViewCell`?

I'd like to have it just like Snapchat by doing the following:

Disable the `UIPageViewController` sliding. Then, as a user is sliding a `UITableViewCell` with the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, when the button is fully revealed, THEN switch the `UIPageViewController` sliding back ON so when the user slides further, it starts to slide to the next view controller.

I think that I'll have to put some of this in the `CustomTableViewCellDelegate` of my `CustomTableViewCell`. Any ideas on how to implement this? I can email my Xcode project to recreate the problem if need be. Thanks.

EDIT: Finally learned how to upload my Xcode Project to GitHub. My project can be found on this link https://github.com/cnowak7/PanGestureTest to recreate the problem.